# Proving that $\max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}}(X_i)$ is a minimal statistics for uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0, \theta] \text{ }, \theta \in [0, \infty)$.
I am to prove that $\max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}}(X_i)$ is a minimal sufficient statistics.

It's easy to show that it is a sufficient statistics (using [factorization theorem](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/)).

I have problems with showing that it is moreover a minimal statistics.
How can I show that if the ratio 
$$\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)}$$
does not depend on $\theta$ then $\max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}}(X_i) = \max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}}(Y_i)$?

Comment: You might consider the contrapositive that if the two maxima are different then the ratio does depend on $\theta$ in the sense that it will be different in the case  $\theta$ between the two maxima compared with the case where $\theta$ is greater than both maxima

Comment: @Henry You're right! That might work!